# Webforms multiple Charts generated as looping from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, foreach, webforms

I am displaying charts on a webform using C# on runtime grabbing chart values from a database.

I am able to do it in a fixed format where I drag and drop the chart control

Here is the code I am using to generate fixed chart control:

```
int Machine_ID = 4;

string sql_getMemoryData = "Select Top 1 Memory_Consumed_Percent from tbl_Machine_Data where Machine_ID =@Machine_ID order by insDate desc";

SqlCommand cmd_getMemoryData = new SqlCommand(sql_getMemoryData, SKcon);
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Machine_ID", machineID);
cmd_getMemoryData.Parameters.Add(param[0]);
SKcon.Open();
        
SqlDataReader dr_getMemoryData = cmd_getMemoryData.ExecuteReader();

if (dr_getMemoryData.HasRows)
{
   if (dr_getMemoryData.Read())
   {
      MemoryUsedPercent = 
      Convert.ToInt32(dr_getMemoryData.GetValue(0));
   }
}

dr_getMemoryData.Close();
SKcon.Close();

MemoryFreePercent = MemoryTotalPercent - MemoryUsedPercent;

Chart_Memory.Titles.Add(MachineName.ToString());
Chart_Memory.Series["Series_Memory"].Palette = ChartColorPalette.SemiTransparent;
Chart_Memory.Series["Series_Memory"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart_Memory.Series["Series_Memory"].Points.AddXY(1, MemoryUsedPercent.ToString());
Chart_Memory.Series["Series_Memory"].Points.AddXY(2, MemoryFreePercent.ToString());
```

I want to load multiple charts on runtime looping from a database. Each chart is simple having one series and one chartarea only.

In the database, there can be any number of charts. How can I generate multiple charts depending on the values from a SQL Server database table values? I am not new to for and while loops but so far scratching my head when it comes to chart control.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are several ways to do this.

However, any time we have a "thing" that we want to "repeat"?

Well, then of course using a repeater works well.

So, if I had one text box on the web page, but I wanted to repeat the text box 5 times, then I would wrap the text box inside of a repeater.

so, lets use the above concept to "repeat" the chart as many times as we need.

I suppose it don't matter a whole lot what the chart does.

but, assuming I drag + drop the chart control onto the web page.

Then assume I am going to feed that chart say one month of data.

So, since we assume/know/want/will "eventually" want multiple charts, then lets setup the code to be passed say the year and month, and then render the chart.

ONCE we have that working, then we will warp that one chart in a repeater, and then have the chart repeat for each month.

Thus, we can say display 1 month of data in the chart (1 chart).

Or, I can display 3 months of data, have 3 charts, each display the one month.

so, I drag + drop in a chart to the web page.

The chart looks like this:
(it does not really matter, since I just used the propty sheet, setup the layout using the property sheet).

So this markup (but, I really don't care/look/see/write by hand the markup).
We ONLY think of this "thing" as a "thing" on the web page.

```
<div id="OneMonth" style="float:left; margin-left: 40px;">
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="578px" Height="391px" BackGradientStyle="LeftRight">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" IsXValueIndexed="True" XValueMember="nDay" XValueType="Int32" 
                YValueMembers="Logons" YValuesPerPoint="6" YValueType="Int32" ChartType="SplineRange"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY>
                    <MajorGrid Interval="5" />
                    <LabelStyle Interval="5" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX Title="" 
                    TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 16.2pt" TitleForeColor="SteelBlue">
                    <MajorGrid Interval="1" IntervalOffset="1" />
                    <LabelStyle Interval="1" IntervalOffset="1" IntervalOffsetType="Number" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" ForeColor="Blue" Name="Title1">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
    </asp:Chart>
</div>
```

Ok, now our code. As noted, in "anticipation" that we going to do this multiple time, I broke out the code in a few bite sized parts.

So, code to load is this: (logon's to a web site for a given month/year)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }


    void LoadData()
    {

        int Y = 2021;
        // int NumMonths = 1;

        LoadGraph(Chart1, Y, 1);

    }


    void LoadGraph(Chart MyChart, int Y, int M)
    {

        // load up the passed chart with data.
        DataTable rstData;
        DateTime dtStart, dtEnd;
        int intDays;

        dtStart = DateAndTime.DateSerial(Y, M, 1);
        intDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtStart.Year, dtStart.Month);
        dtEnd = dtStart.AddDays(intDays - 1);


        rstData = GetData(dtStart, dtEnd);

        MyChart.DataSource = rstData;
        MyChart.DataBind();

        //Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title =
        //    $"Logon Activity for {dtStart.ToString("MMMM")} {dtStart.ToString("yyyy")}";
        MyChart.Titles[0].Text =  $"Logon Activity for {dtStart.ToString("MMMM")} {dtStart.ToString("yyyy")}";
    }
```

Note VERY but beyond VERY close, in "anticipation" of having mutliple charts, now HOW I PASSED the chart control to that routine.

While we ONLY have 1 chart right now, I setup the routine to be PASSED the one chart.

Ok, so the result is this:

[image]

Above that chart, I have the year, and "how many" months (charts) we want to display - (we not done that code yet).

Ok, so our setup is a routine that we "pass" the chart control ALONG with the month + year.

Now, we want to have "many" instances of the chart.

so, we wrap the above chart in a "repeater", and then setup our code to "repeat" the chart for as many times as we require/request.

So, add repeater, move the working chart inside the repeater.

[image]

Now, in above, I have collapsed the div that the chart control is in. I don't really care what is inside of the repeater - but only that we going to repeat it!!!

Ok, so now, we need to feed the repeater the data to repeat.

That data will of course be the date start, date end for each month.

So, remove our first "load" data code.

Enter a year, how many months.

now our code becomes this:

Go button code:

```
protected void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Year = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text);
    int numMonths = Convert.ToInt32(txtMonth.Text);
    DataTable rstRepeat = new DataTable();
    rstRepeat.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
    rstRepeat.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(int));

    for (int m = 1; m <= numMonths; m++)
    {
        DataRow OneRow = rstRepeat.NewRow();
        OneRow["Year"] = Year;
        OneRow["Month"] = m;
        rstRepeat.Rows.Add(OneRow);
    }
    Repeater1.DataSource = rstRepeat;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

So, above creates our "list" of what we want to repeat. A simple year and month table. We simple feed that to our "repeater", and it will repeat the chart control now for each month.

The repeater control thus fire for each data row from above (one month and year).

So, in the item data bound of the repeater, we get that one row (month/year), get the chart control, and call our orignal routine that feeds the chart control one month of data.

this:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item |
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView rRowData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        // get chart control instance
        Chart OneChart = (Chart)e.Item.FindControl("Chart1");
        LoadGraph(OneChart, (int)rRowData["Year"], (int)rRowData["Month"]);
    }
}
```

So, now the result is this:

[image]

So, I could say type in 12, and I will have 12 charts, each for one month.